# BIOS boot options disappeared, can't create options or boot into any OS

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios, multi-boot

My system is and ASUS laptop dual-booting Windows and Fedora Linux, using Grub, the OSes are installed in a NVMe SSD while most of my data is in another HD.
Everything was working fine when today I rebooted (from my Linux partition) to boot into windows, at that point however, the grub menu did not come up, instead I was greeted by the BIOS configuration menu.

I am still having a hard time understanding what is going on.

In the BIOS configuration menu, the list of boot options is completely empty, and even the "create boot option" menu selection disappeared.

In the advanced settings I can see two selections: "SATA Configuration" and "NVMe Configuration", if I select either of them I can see the information of my HD and SSD respectively, suggesting that at least they are detected.

I have already tried updating the BIOS but that did not change anything.
The only boot option available in the Boot Override section, called "Launch EFI shell from filesystem device", does not work (a warning appears saying "Not Found").

My previous setup, in order to allow for Linux to work was as follows:

- Fast Boot: disabled
- Secure Boot: disabled
- Inside SATA Configuration: SATA Mode Selection set to AHCI (The only other option is something about Intel Optane acceleration but that doesn't work with Linux)

Funnily enough, if I enable Intel Optane, the BIOS detects the boot configuration, however something is definetly wrong with them because none of them start, they appear to come from the HD while the OSes are actually installed in the SSD and the "NVMe Configuration" option in the advanced settings disappears (does that mean the BIOS is not detecting the SSD anymore?? IDK)

Finally, I have tried booting into a live USB of Fedora and it worked fine, from there I tried to access both HD and SSD and I could access them without any issue. I checked the partitioning with the gnome disks utility and I ran a SMART self check test on the SSD, everything seems to be working fine (my biggest fear was a hardware failure but all of this seems to discredit this hypotesis)

Has anyone got any idea what the hell is wrong with my system?

Comment: Perhaps reset BIOS to default values, restart, back to BIOS and set it up again.

Comment: @John I already tried to restore the default settings, nothing changed, in the question I mentioned that I even tried to update the bios but that didn't help either.

Comment: Just for reference, "Launch EFI shell from filesystem device" expects a copy of the [EFI Shell](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Obtaining_UEFI_Shell) to be placed at `\shellx64.efi` on your EFI System Partition. Might be worth trying to install it so that you could look around from the inside. (The shell has a "bcfg" command for managing boot entries, among other things, and can be used to manually run GRUB or other EFI programs.)

Comment: One thing I noticed through my live usb of linux is that my EFI system partition is on the HD while the OSes are installed in the SSD, could that be ralated to the problem? if so why would it appear today out of nowhere as I didn't change anything about my setup recently

Comment: Use the live USB to examine the SMART disk information. Perhaps it's a disk problem, so take backups if needed before tackling the problem.

Comment: @harrymc done that no problems with the disk, also my data is already separate from the OS installations so I don't really fear losing data

Comment: I was finally able to solve the issue (although I still don't know why it happened in the first place as it worked fine), the solution was to move the EFI system partition to the SSD drive and after that it was able to boot into both linux and windows. Of course when I booted windows it decided to eat my GRUB installation so I also had to reinstall GRUB. Now the problem appears to be solved and maybe I'll write an actual (and more accurate) answer in case it may be useful to other people. If anyone has some idea of why the problem suddenly appeared please enlighten me. (maybe some update?)